# Erro ao realizar requisições a API utiizando Axios e Vue-resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, vue.js, axios

Estava consumindo dados de uma API utilizando XHR e estava funcionando muito bem, mas houve algumas mudanças no projeto e surgiu a necessidade de utilizar o Vue. Tentei realizar as mesmas requisições utilizando o Axios e logo depois o Vue Resource mas em ambos não tive sucesso.

Código utilizando XHR:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(false);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open("POST", "api/url");
xhr.send(data);
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});
```

Código utilizando Axios:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'api/url',
  data: JSON.stringify(false),
  withCredentials: true
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Código utilizando Vue-resource:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify(false);
  this.$http.post("api/url", data, {
  headers: {
      credentials : true,
  }}).then(resp => console.log(resp));
```

Utilizando tanto Axios quanto Vue-resource tenho o seguinte erro:

```
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

Parece um problema de CORS.

Comment: A mensagem indica que sim. Se voce tem acesso a API, tente liberar o CORS nela.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo erro, ele está conseguindo acessar a api mas é bloqueado pelo cors. Tem que ver essa questão na api, não no seu site

Answer (score 0):

Você está tendo erro de CORS, que é um sistema de segurança que os navegadores utilizam.

> CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (Compartilhamento de recursos com
> origens diferentes) é um mecanismo que usa cabeçalhos adicionais HTTP
> para informar a um navegador que permita que um aplicativo Web seja
> executado em uma origem (domínio) com permissão para acessar recursos
> selecionados de um servidor em uma origem distinta. Um aplicativo Web
> executa uma requisição cross-origin HTTP ao solicitar um recurso que
> tenha uma origem diferente (domínio, protocolo e porta) da sua própria
> origem.

Pode ser que a documentação oficial te ajude a entender melhor o erro.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS